# If a webpage contains an iFrame, would the iframe be loaded through the proxy server used to view the page?

Tags: iframe, proxy

I am trying to create a web proxy server similar to those available online: you access the main webpage, enter the url in a field and then, via the web proxy server itself, it would open the page in another window/frame.

The question is: which connection would the iframe use to open the webpage? The connection from the person who opened the page or the web proxy's local connection?

I am trying to prevent adding the proxy server details in my local IE, which is heavily audited and block blogs, which are sometimes very useful to my line of work. I can, however, access my home web server via port 80 or even 8080.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to create your own proxy script, say in PHP, the way it will work is that when you enter a URL to access the URL will be sent to your proxy script on your server, then the server will establish a socket connection to the URL you have defined to access the site and then return it to your browser as if it was stored locally on your own server. This is a common method of bypassing locality or web browsing restrictions, especially in places with highly restrictive internet policies. There are a large number of free web-based proxy scripts available on the internet that you can use which are simple PHP websites which act as proxy servers for you and save you from needing to change browser settings or needing to design your own from the ground up.

I would be remiss if I didn't state for the record though that what you are proposing would more than likely be seen as a breach of workplace conditions, especially if you are using this to bypass existing restrictions on the workplace internet connection and could open you up to disciplinary action should it be discovered.